# Elixer attacks in town hall 8

Tags: clash-of-clans

My regular army is 20 wizards, a couple skeletons, a hogrider, and the rest are giants. This usually gets me 3 stars but sucks because I don't get enough loot to make up for the training cost (when including spells).

What's a better attack strategy for TH 8 that focuses on gaining elixir? I have valkyries but no golems or pekas yet. At the moment I'm upgrading my barbarian king to level 9.

Comment: Are you raiding for loot or stars? That is a key question

Comment: @nickson104 loot

Comment: barchning  with full collectors raid

Comment: Is this question really too broad? There are only so many ways to build a cheap, yet effective raiding army. In fact, I'd make it more broad and remove the player-specific information out of the question so it is more widely applicable.

Comment: If the best troops to farm with are tier 1 troops (due to low cost) then that is like Archers, Barbs and Goblins, how is that broad. Its the complete opposite its lacking in variety.

Comment: @Ellesedil and daedric, you can vote to reopen by clicking the link at the bottom of the question

Comment: I'm not a [3000 rep user](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/close-questions), so all I can do is comment.

Answer (score 4):

The most common elixir/gold raid strategy up until around TH7/TH8 is [BARCH](http://www.withoutthesarcasm.com/tips-tricks-rapid-raiding-around-town-hall-7-clash-clans/).  This strategy basically targets undefended (or lightly defended) collectors near the outside of mostly abandoned bases.  The article I linked has examples of what to look for, what to train, and how to maximize your raiding efficiency.

You basically don't want to be punching into the center of bases, just attacking the "easy money" around the outside.  It involves a *lot* of skipping, either because the base doesn't have enough resources or they're not in undefended collectors.

Spell wise, you can take lightning to kill mortars that would normally trash your barbs/archers.  Earthquake can be good too, but it relies on DE which might be at a premium for you.

If you've got DE to burn (chances are you don't, but still...) try adding minions to the mix, this strategy is referred to as "BAM."  Sometimes, people mix in wall breakers to punch a little further in, it's worth experimenting with to see what works for you at least.

The December 2015 patch changed the meta significantly, so now it's actually useful to hit town halls and/or earn stars when attacking.  Make sure you've got a clan castle (and join a clan if you're not in one already!) to hold the star loot.

As I got into the higher stages of TH8, I started switching out the barbarians for PEKKAs. ("PARCH?")  Even though it seems like PEKKAs should be a waste, if you can hit higher level bases and take more of the collectors, it ends up profiting anyhow.  If you train 1 PEKKA per barrack, you can use overtraining to always have a set ready and/or get 2 nearly back-to-back attacks.

For that strategy, I suggest taking heal spells to make the PEKKAs last a bit longer.

Comment: I saw a very interesting base. Basically all the elixir drills and storage were very easy to get to, but the TH and more than 50% of the base was inside the walls and heavily guarded. For example, the elixir storage was in the corners of the map with nothing around them.

Comment: @Celeritas, yeah, there's some really... unique bases out there.  Some folks don't care about their elixir, so they'd rather you attack the base, get their elixir, and then fail to do any other damage.  I myself did something similar when I was high TH8 and couldn't use elixir anymore.

Answer (score 4):

**Barching**

Yep I definitely recommend using two barracks per troop dedicated to archers and barbarians.

Its a fast and efficient method for reaping the rewards.

But don't attack just any old base, attack bases that show you they have a decent amount of resources e.g: 200k of each and 1k DE.
But you don't want to be trying to three star or get the loot in the storages so you need to make sure the loot is in the collectors on the outside / edges of the base. I will only attack if I can see at least 1/4 of the storage is full.

See how the elixir is visually raised?
[image: Visualization of Collector Fullness]

And remember that if their collectors are full but the overall loot is low, its probably because of the Town Hall loot penalty (The base is a lower TH than your's so you get less loot).

This site could help (I found the image there):
http://cocland.com/tricks-and-tips/farming-collectors-tips

Answer (score 1):

I think i have a better solution.
As you can see i am on townhall 8:-
[image: Town hall 8]

I have came this far with only attacking deadbases(Deadbases are bases which have no loot in their gold storages but they have full gold mines and elixir collectors) by attacking with only barbarians, archers and goblins.

Comment: I am confused as to why you have a screenshot in your answer....  but the strategy you describe is sometimes refereed to as 'barch'

Comment: @ColinD technically it would be barchlin in this case

Answer (score -1):

Check if this strategy fits your needs: [Loot Raid](http://clashofclans.wikia.com/wiki/Attack_Strategies/Loot_Raid)

> This simple yet effective strategy will teach you how to get the
>   resources you need for that expensive upgrade.
>
> Minimum Housing Space Required: 135
>
> - 50 Goblins: 3,000 Elixir
> - 15 Giants: 18,750 Elixir
> - 5 Wall Breakers:10,000 Elixir
> - 2 Healing Spells: 33,000 Elixir
>     **Total:** 64,750 Elixir
>
> ### Executiuon
>
> ### FIND THE PERFECT BASE:
>
> Keep looking until you find a base with what you're looking for, say
>   you want to upgrade your town hall, we all know that that's EXPENSIVE,
>   so, how would you get the money in the first place? Raids, find a
>   partially weak base with about 120,000+ gold, if that base has already
>   been raided, go for the gold mines.
>
> ### THE RAID
>
> This is the fun part, first, place a giant or two near a tower
>   guarding your loot, when the defenses are locked on the giant, place
>   two wall breakers as close to the gold storage as possible, then send
>   out the rest of your giants, then your horde of goblins, if your
>   giants are low on health, use a healing potion, same thing with the
>   goblins, too.

Comment: while external links can include helpful information, it is generally best if you can summarize the information here in case the link dies

Comment: @Dragonrage I edited the answer, what do you think?

Comment: should be good now.